# work by strings and list in python

Tags: python, string, list, bioinformatics

I have 5 set of lists and some of strings in those lists are repetitive

now! I wanna know the number of repetition! for example the word "A" is in all of my lists by "B" is just in "3" or "C" is in 4 of them.

How can I sort this problem, by using remove() I faced to wrong answer

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried collections Counter? Can you provide your current datastructure and your expected result?

Comment: The second-top-voted answer on the linked duplicate shows how to use `collections.Counter` in an idiomatic way.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please give an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Take a look at [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

```
from collections import Counter
a = ['a','a','b','b']
b = ['b','b','c','d']
c = a+b
cnt = Counter()
for x in c:
     cnt[x] +=1

print(cnt)
    Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 4, 'c': 1, 'd': 1})
```

The above will get you counts of each but it seems like you're more concerned at a list level.

```
from collections import defaultdict
f = defaultdict(list)
a = ['a','a','b','b']
b = ['b','b','c','d']
c = ['e','f','g','h']
d = a + b + c
 for i in d:
     f[i] = 0
     if i in b:
         f[i] += 1
     if i in c:
         f[i] +=1
     if i in a:
         f[i] +=1
print (f)

defaultdict(list,
                {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'f': 1, 'g': 1, 'h': 1})
```

Comment: This is a very good example of how not to use `Counter`.

Comment: Why bother at all with `Counter` if you're going to use it like a defaultdict? The point of it is to be able to write `Counter(a+b)`.

Comment: The edited-in second code snippet is inaccurate (and quite verbose) as well.

Comment: YES! it was useful! THANK YOU